# Can not reproduce error: Class constructor DateTimeFormat cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: javascript, object-detection

I found the following in my JavaScript error logs today:

> Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor DateTimeFormat cannot be invoked without 'new'

I've tested Chrome 34, 76 and 81 and was not able to reproduce the error with the following line where the error was reported from:

```
if (window['Intl'] && typeof Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions == 'function' && typeof Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone == 'string')
{
 t = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
}
```

The user agent:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; HWI-AL00 Build/HUAWEIHWI-AL00; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/76.0.3809.89 Mobile Safari/537.36 T7/11.22 SP-engine/2.18.0 baiduboxapp/11.22.0.10 (Baidu; P1 9)

This UA stuck around long enough to trigger an error though not really anything else.

In what browser / version can I reproduce this issue?

Comment: https://user-agents.net/applications/baidu-box-app is the first google hit

Comment: Anyway, the error message is right: [you *should* use `new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat#Syntax)